# scala : @Suite.SuiteClasses is not working for scala project

Tags: java, scala, junit, sbt

I am new to the scala, I need to convert java code to scala :

Level2TestReporter.class is in jar file called iteser.jar
Level2TestReporter.class contains @test method

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Level2TestReporter.class})
class  OrganizationRegexModelComponentTester  implements ITester {

    public List<Map<String, Object>> testComponent(Map<String, Object> input, Map<String, Object> metadata) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    return list ;
}
```

How to write in scala I tried

```
@RunWith(classOf[Suite])
@Suite.SuiteClasses(Array(classOf[Level2TestReporter]))
class  OrganizationRegexModelComponentTester  extends ITester {

  override def testComponent( input: java.util.Map[String, Object], metadata: java.util.Map[String, Object] ): util.List[util.Map[String,AnyRef]]  = {

  val list: util.List[Map[String, AnyRef]] = new util.ArrayList[Map[String, AnyRef]]

  list
}
```

but `sbt test` is not invoking test methods Please help

Comment: where are your files located, and what is the content in your sbt file? more info will help in finding the solution